# apllication with Entityframework and localDB Crash during runtime

Tags: .net, entity-framework, localdb, .net-framework-version

my visual basic application works fine during debug on my development machine , but when i build it and use on other system it crash with this error:

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   airline crew managment system
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   5373bf49
Problem Signature 04:   System.Data
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4ba1e064
Problem Signature 07:   255b
Problem Signature 08:   6c
Problem Signature 09:   System.Data.Entity.Core.Entity
OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1065

Read our privacy statement:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

is there because i don't have SQL Server installed on my other machines(this app use LocalDB) or because i'm using .net 4.0.
any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, simply you should first install sqlLocalDB.msi then run your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have targeted your application to .Net 4.0 then that needs to be installed on every machine that your application runs on.

You can see that .Net 4.0 is NOT installed on your production machine because the event name is `CLR20r3`, indicating the .Net 2.0 runtime is handling your application there.

Comment: no, actulay after installing .net 4.0 i stil get this error.

Comment: Me too. I packaged .NET 4.5 and Sql Server 2012 and I still get this error but it says Entity Framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, when you using SqlLocalDB in local PC, there is some setting in the App.setting or Web.Config, just remove it before you build and run it in your server. In this way, you need not to install SqlLocalDB/ SQL Express in the server.